# My sql query not work with math operators

Tags: mysql, sql

Where is a problem because I try count values using sql queries:

`(SELECT quantity FROM db WHERE no='998')` this is fine

but `(('500') - (SELECT quantity FROM db WHERE no='998'))` // incorrect syntax near -

But I need to use constant 500. Where is problem

Comment: Don't put numbers in single quotes. Single quotes are only for character literals.

Comment: Why all the parenthesis? Is this statement part of a larger query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT 500 - quantity
FROM db
WHERE no = 998;
```

A `select` statement needs to start with a select.  In addition, numeric constants should not use single quotes (although that has no effect on whether the query parses or runs).

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT 500-quantity FROM db WHERE no='998'`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT 500 - quantity FROM db WHERE no='998'
-- or if the no in the where clause is an integer and not a string:
-- SELECT 500 - quantity FROM db WHERE no=998
```

Or if you have to use a constant string literal:

```
SELECT '500' - quantity FROM db WHERE no='998'
```

in this case MySQL would implicitly convert it to a suitable integer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 500 - COUNT(quantity)
FROM db
WHERE no='998';
```

SQL query always begin by `SELECT` keyword.